# Is there a way to run an SQL query and disconnect without waiting for completion?

Tags: postgresql, asynchronous

I have a query like this

```
CREATE TABLE AS 
SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE 
WHERE some_complicated_query
```

It takes about 4 hours to execute this query, but when I have a connection issue or any other problems the query just fails and never finishes, and I need to re-run it every time.

Probably someone knows: is there any way to run a query in parallel without waiting for completion?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can run it via crontab, or using pgAgent from the database server itself (or connect to the server via SSH and use `nohup` if available).

Comment: Or `tmux` or `screen`...

Comment: yeah, but it won't help for connectivity issues, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The query will always fail if the client goes away, because it cannot communicate the result. It may take a long time for the server to notice that the client is gone, but eventually the query will fail.

What you can do is to start the client on the database server, then the connection won't fail and the statement will run to completion. On UNIX you can do something like

```
nohup psql -c 'CREATE ...' &
```

to start the client in the background, then you don't need to wait until it is done.

Comment: yeah, but it won't help for connectivity issues, it's better to divide the job on small pieces somehow and implement an idempotent script to run it, thank you for confirming my thoughts!